# Redis - I'm trying to import a file in my NodeJS without assigning it to a variable, so far it doesn't works

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require, node-redis

## Brief

I'm trying to import a file containing redundant's code in consumers. So far it seems my file is doesn't read by the consumer which returns me:

> function getAsync is not defined

but it however defined in file1.js

Here my snippet:

file1.js:

```
const redis=require("redis"); 
rejson = require('redis-rejson');
const {promisify} = require('util'); 

rejson(redis); /* important - this must come BEFORE creating the client */
let client= redis.createClient({
    port:6380,
    host:'localhost',
    // password:process.env.rPass
});  

const setAsync = promisify(client.json_set).bind(client);
const arrappendAsync = promisify(client.json_arrappend).bind(client);
const getAsync = promisify(client.json_get).bind(client); 
const existsAsync= promisify(client.exists).bind(client);
```

file2.js:

```
require("./redisConnect")
async function getUser(){ 
    let res=await getAsync("userStock", ".")
        .catch((err) => console.error(err)); 
    resArray= JSON.parse(res)
    console.log("userStock res: ", resArray[0]);
    client.quit()
}

// use userId to filter relevant array 
getUser()
```

So how handle this situation?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In file1.js, you need to do:

```
module.exports = getAsync;
```

Then in file2.js, do this:

```
var getAsync = require('./file1.js')
```

Comment: I would just pour the file1 in the file2, I have seen is possible using packages like babel and for example this question on stackoverflow for basic use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426770/node-js-require-without-storing-it-into-a-variable

Comment: I don't understand your concern. Yes, requiring a file will execute the code in the file.  Generally we use export/require to modularize code, so we can reuse it in other files.

Comment: well, I would to be able to make this kind of stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39286176/9817602